# Calculation of index returns for specific timeframe for each row using (as an option) for loop

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, finance

I am not too experienced with programming, and I got stuck in a research project in the asset management field.

**My Goal:**
I have 2 dataframes,- one [containing aside from others columns "European short date"," SP150030after", "SP1500365before" (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9ghJ.png) and second containing [column "Dates" and "S&P 1500_return"(Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc9F6.png). For each row in the first dataframe, I want to calculate cumulative returns of S&P 1500 for 365 days before the date in column "European short date" and cumulative returns of S&P 1500 for 30 days after the date in column "European short date" and put these results in columns "SP150030after" and "SP1500365before".

These returns are to be calculated using a second Dataframe. "S&P 1500_return" column in the second data frame for each date represents "daily return of S&P 1500 market index + 1". So, for example to get cumulative returns over 1 year before 31.12.2020 in first dataframe, I would have to calculate the product of values in column "S&P 1500_return" from  the second dataframe for each day present (trading day) in the dataframe 2 during the period 31.12.2019 - 30.12.2020.

**What I have tried so far:**
I turned "European short date" in DataFrame 1 and "Date" in Dataframe 2 to be index fields and though about approaching my goal through "for" loop. I tried to turn "European short date" to be "List" to use it to iterate through the dataframe 1, but I get the following error: "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:18: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead".

**Here is my code so far:**

```
Main_set = pd.read_excel('...')

Main_set = pd.DataFrame(Main_set)
Main_set['European short date'] = pd.to_datetime(Main_set['European short date'], format='%d.%m.%y', errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Main_set = Main_set.set_index('European short date')
Main_set.head(5)

Indexes = pd.read_excel('...')
Indexes = pd.DataFrame(Indexes)
Indexes['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Indexes['Date'], format='%d.%m.%y', errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Indexes = Indexes.set_index('Date')

SP1500DailyReturns = Indexes[['S&P 1500 SUPER COMPOSITE - PRICE INDEX']]
SP1500DailyReturns['S&P 1500_return'] = (SP1500DailyReturns['S&P 1500 SUPER COMPOSITE - PRICE INDEX'] / SP1500DailyReturns['S&P 1500 SUPER COMPOSITE - PRICE INDEX'].shift(1)) 
SP1500DailyReturns.to_csv('...')



Main_set['SP50030after'] = np.zeros(326)

import math

dates = Main_set['European short date'].to_list()
dates.head()
for n in dates:
  Main_set['SP50030after'] = math.prod(arr)
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In case it will be useful for someone, I solved the problem by using a for loop and dividing the problem in more steps:

```
for n in dates:
  Date = pd.Timestamp(n) 
  DateB4 =  Date - pd.Timedelta("365 days") 
  DateAfter =  Date + pd.Timedelta("30 days")  
  ReturnsofPeriodsBackwards = SP1500DailyReturns.loc[str(DateB4) : str(Date), 'S&P 1500_return'] 
  Main_set.loc[str(Date), 'SP500365before'] = np.prod(ReturnsofPeriodsBackwards)  
  ReturnsofPeriodsForward = SP1500DailyReturns.loc[str(Date) : str(DateAfter), 'S&P 1500_return'] 
  Main_set.loc[str(Date), 'SP50030after'] = np.prod(ReturnsofPeriodsForward)
```